# Android bundle's raw file size is something weird

Tags: android, android-app-bundle

[image]

The final aab file size is about 73MB, but the android studio estimate as 28MB.
What is the matter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are seeing is perfectly normal.

Raw file size is the total size of the files together in the App Bundle that you will upload to the Play Console.

Google Play then optimises the App Bundle to generate Apks for different device configurations. E.g. pixel density, language etc.

> Google Play uses your app bundle to generate and serve optimized APKs for each device configuration, so only the code and resources that are needed for a specific device are downloaded to run your app. You no longer have to build, sign, and manage multiple APKs to optimize support for different devices, and users get smaller, more-optimized downloads.3

This means that the user will receive only the resources their device needs, which results in the lower app download size.

More information: https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle